# Appium: How to get current window?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I have Appium 1.4.13

```
IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(appiumUrl, desiredCapabilities);
```

How do I get current window (UIAWindow)? How do I get all elements on that window?

Answer (score 0):

hi Artem appium tool only automates the app not android functionalities so you cant retrieve like home, settings window just like selenium does browser automation not the windows system (for that we use external tools like AutoIt and Sikuli), To retrieve app handles we use `getcontextHandles()` method to know we are in native app or Web view... hope this helps

Comment: Looks like those tools are for desktop. Are there things like that for mobile?